# queue from the stl

Tags: c++, stl, g++, standard-library

I am trying to get the following code to compile using g++ 4.2.1 and am receiving the following errors

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{    
    queue<int> myqueue();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        myqueue.push(i);

    cout << myqueue.size();

    return 0;
}
```

ERRORS:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char* const*)’:
main.cpp:10: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘myqueue’, which is of non-class type ‘std::queue<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > > ()()’
main.cpp:12: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘myqueue’, which is of non-class type ‘std::queue<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > > ()()’
```

Any ideas as to why? I tried in Eclipse, X-Code and through the terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[C++ FAQ Lite § 10.2](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2)

> #### Is there any difference between `List x;` and `List x();`?
>
> A *big* difference!
>
> Suppose that `List` is the name of some class. Then function `f()` declares a local `List` object called `x`:
>
> ```
> void f()
> {
>   List x;     // Local object named x (of class List)
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> But function `g()` declares a function called `x()` that returns a `List`:
>
> ```
> void g()
> {
>   List x();   // Function named x (that returns a List)
>   ...
> }
> ```

Replace `queue<int> myqueue();` by `queue<int> myqueue;` and you'll be fine.

Comment: If further research is required, this is also sometimes known as the "most vexing parse": http://www.google.com/search?q=most+vexing+parse

Comment: that did it! thanks a lot. Out of curiosity, is there no constructor for the queue? I had the parentheses because I had to be calling the constructor. Or would I only do that if I were new-ing the object?

Comment: The version without parentheses does call the no-arg constructor.

Comment: `Foo bar;` constructs `bar` using the constructor `Foo::Foo()`.  `Foo bar(a,b,c);` constructs `bar` using the constructor `Foo::Foo(a,b,c)`.  `new Foo;` and `new Foo()` both construct a `Foo`, but mean subtly different things.  Yes, this is inconsistent and horrible.  That's C++ :)  This is why some people prefer to write `Foo bar = Foo();` and `Foo bar = Foo(a,b,c);` but I don't really like that either...

Comment: so Foo bar(); does NOT call the constructor Foo::Foo()? It must not if it produces a compile error.

Comment: No, `Foo bar()` does not construct anything.  Instead, it is a declaration "in this scope, `bar` is a function taking no arguments and returning `Foo`".  Of course, with only a declaration and no definition, you can't do anything useful with `bar`...